# enum class definition process

Tags: python, enums

I am reading the enum source code, so

```
class Enum(metaclass=EnumMeta)
```

there's a `__call__` and `__new__` method in EnumMeta and a `__new__` in Enum, my question is when we instantiate an Enum class, why the `__call__` of the meta class is called, instead of the `__new__` of the Enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__new__` in any class is used to create instances of that class.  So:

```
class Buffer:
    def __new__(cls, size):
        instance = object.__new__(cls)
        instance.storage = bytearray(size)
        return instance
```

and in the REPL:

```
>>>> buffer = Buffer(32)
>>> buffer
<__main__.Buffer object at 0x7fb146867a60>

>>> type(buffer)
<class '__main__.Buffer'>
```

So if `Buffer.__new__` is used to create an instance of `Buffer`, what is `Buffer` itself an instance of?

```
>>> type(Buffer)
<class 'type'>
```

Okay, `Buffer` is an instance of `type` -- so, just like `Buffer.__new__` is used to create an instance of `Buffer`, `type.__new__` is used to create an instance of `type`, which `Buffer` is.

Turning this back to `Enum` and `EnumMeta`:  `EnumMeta.__new__` is used to create instances of itself, which are Enum classes, and `Enum.__new__` is used to create Enum instances, which are its members.

Part of the magic of `Enum`, and probably also part of the confusion, is that the members *are* instances of the class, even though they are listed in the body of the Enum class (usually such things are just attributes, like the `storage` used above in `Buffer`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I understand my confusion. The __new__ indeed get called when we try to instantiate Enum, I will post my understanding as well.